# Calling an action with parameter .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `MyMessages` model that I put data into when the user logs in. it includes all the data needed.
for every message that they have I do the following in view

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyMessagesCount; i++)
                    {
                       <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center mt-2">
                           <a>@Model.MessagesTitles[i]</a>
                           

                       </li>
```

When the user clicks on each of the `<a>`, I want to show them that message in more details in a separate view where I pass `MessageID` to.
How can I achieve that? How can I have all the `<a>` call the same action but with different `MessageID` as a parameter? (Something like this `/User/Usermessages?MessageID=20`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anchor tag helper

```
<li>
    <a asp-controller="user" 
        asp-action="messages" 
        asp-area="" 
        asp-route-messageId="@Model.MessagesTitles[i].MessageId">
        @Model.MessagesTitles[i]
    </a>
</li>
```

`asp-route-{parameter}`: the parameter there is the name of the parameter you define in your action.

You can read more on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

In the Index.cshtml page, you could directly set the a tag `href` attribute.

Code sample as below:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<MyMessages> messages = new List<MyMessages>()
        {
            new MyMessages(){ MessageId=1001, MessageTitile="AA"},
            new MyMessages(){MessageId =1002, MessageTitile="BB"},
            new MyMessages(){MessageId=1003, MessageTitile="CC"} 
        };
        return View(messages);
    }

    public IActionResult Details(int messageId)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Index.cshtml page:

```
    @model List<SignalRChatSample.Models.MyMessages>

    <ul>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center mt-2">
                <a href="/Home/Details?messageId=@Model[i].MessageId.ToString()">@Model[i].MessageTitile</a> 
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Then, the result like this (The url: `Https://localhost:5001/Home/Details?messageId=1002`):

[image]

Besides, as David said, you could also send the parameters via the route.